# How to use the serializer in part

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have several viewsets, several endpoints in them use one serializer. One endpoint does not even have a Meta class, 
It performs a certain action and uses the same serializer in the method to_representation. In this serializer I use the methodfield like this:

```
some_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
def get_some_field(self, obj):
    return bool(obj.something_attr)
```

something_attr I get in viewset in

```
 queryset =MyModel.objects.annotate(something_attr=(...))
```

In others viewsets there is no such field, so they use other queriesets. Can I work around this problem without creating a bunch of additional serializers. My thanks!

Comment: What's the problem you are facing here?

Comment: The problem is that I touched on the existing serializer, and I wanted to know if there was an opportunity not to use additional methodfields 
if I can not get the attribute of the model, well, for example, I could wrap it in if obj.something_attr: but it would be a very stupid solution, and it does not even look like a crutch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding you're trying to use a single serializer class with different views - but each view need different fields, right?

```
class DynamicFieldSerializerMixin:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

You can use this mixin to define fields dynamically for each view for a single serializer class. Just pass `fields=[]` keyword argument with list of field names.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like something that I just need